# AWS Beanstalk Install Private Github Module via NPM Results In Authentication Issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to install a private github module via npm on an AWS Beanstalk instance.

I'm using a Github personal access token to authenticate with github and access the repo.

My `package.json` lists the dependency like this:

`"privatepackage": "git+https://jaf91ja9jasflkjasf98109asf10asdf:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user123/privatepackage.git"`

However, on Beanstalk I get the following error when deploying:

```
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/tmp/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com...
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com...
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this problem? I've found similar questions and solutions (such as the one at the following link), but wondered if you found anything better.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993092/how-to-use-a-private-npm-registry-on-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing ssh key on your machine and adding same on github.

Please look into [generating-ssh-keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) which might helps you to resolve this issue.

Comment: But, I don't need ssh because I'm using a personal access token.

Comment: Okay, Do you have access rights for that repo. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, full access with the appropriate scopes.