# Using npm private modules on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, private

I am attempting to give permission to my Elastic Beanstalk application on AWS to use my npm auth token in order to find and download my private npm module. I have tried everything here: [Relevant Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993092/how-to-use-a-private-npm-registry-on-elastic-beanstalk/37866227#37866227)

I have had no luck and documentation does not really exist. Anyone able to actually make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a private npm registry on Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993092/how-to-use-a-private-npm-registry-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?