# Define private registry in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-private-modules

We have a private npm repository based on [Sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia)

What should I define in `package.json` that some packages will be installed from Synopia rather then from global npm repository?

If I install it from command line I can run: `npm install <package_name> --registry <http://<server:port>`

P.S. tried to google and looked in official NPM documentation but have found nothing.

Comment: what about adding the path to your private library in the dependencies in package.json.                                                                        "dependencies": {
 <youre_repo_name>:"git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org<path_to_your_repo>"
}

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One of the method i know that is by .npmrc
You can also use .npmrc also inside the project

set configuration like this

```
registry = http://10.197.142.28:8081/repository/npm-internal/
init.author.name = Himanshu sharma
init.author.email = rmail@email.com
init.author.url = http://blog.example.com
# an email is required to publish npm packages
email=youremail@email.com
always-auth=true
_auth=YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=
```

auth can be generate by
         username:password
echo -n 'admin:admin123' | openssl base64

output YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=

Comment: Can i create an npmrc file in my source code folder?

Comment: Yes . Its `.npmrc` file dot is also there . When i worked i placed it, side by package.json .

Comment: Be careful. Using this, you store the credentials in plain text in your repository. Encoding the credentials in base64 is the same as plain text

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of sinopia is a private `registry` and a `proxy` at the same time. You can use [**uplinks**](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/blob/master/wiki/uplinks.md) install all your packages from one registry entry point. Sinopia is able to route to any registry if the local storage is not able to resolve the dependency. By default, he [points](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/blob/master/conf/default.yaml#L22) to `npmjs` .

So, if you set your configuration like

```
   # a list of other known repositories we can talk to
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

packages:
  '@*/*':
    # scoped packages
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs

  '**':
    # allow all users (including non-authenticated users) to read and
    # publish all packages
    #
    # you can specify usernames/groupnames (depending on your auth plugin)
    # and three keywords: "$all", "$anonymous", "$authenticated"
    access: $all

    # allow all known users to publish packages
    # (anyone can register by default, remember?)
    publish: $authenticated

    # if package is not available locally, proxy requests to 'npmjs' registry
    proxy: npmjs
```

You should be able to resolve all your dependencies independently of the source of each of them

btw: `sinopia` has no longer maintained.