# EACCES: permission denied with Elastic Beanstalk deployment

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my node.js app via `eb create`, but am getting the following error:

```
2020/05/17 02:15:37.303673 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:npm WARN deprecated buffer@4.9.1: This version of 'buffer' is out-of-date. You must update to v4.9.2 or newer
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.5.0 and node@12.16.2 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/app/staging/node_modules/canvas/build'
```

I have a `.ebextensions/00_canvas.cfg` that has:

```
packages:
    yum:
        cairo: []
        cairo-devel: []
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
        giflib-devel: []
        libpng-devel: []
```

and a `.ebextensions/01_permissions.cfg`:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_npm_permission.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /var/app/staging/node_modules/canvas
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `unsafe-perm=true` to the `.npmrc` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63689721/1062614