# How to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk using the CLI when you have Private NPM Packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We use several namespaced private packages through NPM.

When we attempt to deploy as we always have using the EB CLI (`eb deploy`) everything is fine until EB attempts to run `npm i`. This causes the deployment to fail as EB does not have access to our NPM Organization's Packages.

I found [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993092/how-to-use-a-private-npm-registry-on-elastic-beanstalk) from 4+ years ago with solutions that do not seem to work.

We've resorted to the workaround of manually 'zipping' the files locally and uploading it in the GUI.

How can we allow our Elastic Beanstalk Instances to deploy with our private packages via the `eb deploy` command?

Comment: I feel like the old answer that you linked is almost correct, but the fact that the path that is used is (`/tmp/.npmrc`) feels wrong to me. The [docs for npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) specifies `/etc/npmrc` which may work better. It may also be worth trying to put the secret directly in the ebextension (i.e. without the `NPM_TOKEN` variable), in case the substitution doesn't work properly anymore.

Comment: Will give this a shot

Comment: Doesnt seem to fix the issue.

Comment: I wonder if this other issue is related. See these two pages: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-eaccess-error/ and https://medium.com/quick-code/how-i-automatically-deployed-typescript-to-elastic-beanstalk-to-speed-up-server-development-22b89870e159

Comment: The AWS support page linked by stefansundin mentions the following: "Create a file named .npmrc in the root directory of your application source bundle." 
Did you try it @MattWeber? Where did you try to put your NPM registry credentials?

Answer (score 0):

The [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow) cover it well. The problem is, for some reason the environment variable, `NPM_TOKEN` isn't read and it fails. We fixed by hardcoding a read-only, IP whitelisted token into the `.npmrc` file.